# display date 90 days earlier form CURRENT (ANSI C)

Tags: c, mfc, ansi-c

Is there an easy way to calculate 90 days earlier than current? For example if it is 31 of May today, what is the date 90 days earlier? Is there a function to do so? Thanks

Comment: First of all you need to decide how to represent dates. You have mentioned a somewhat unholy blend of ANSI C and MFC. Which is it to be? As far as I know, MFC is a C++ library, and the MS compiler does  not even support ANSI C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `COleDateTime` [(link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38wh24td.aspx) and `COleDateTimeSpan` [(link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb7yw6f3.aspx) classes could be used.

```
#include <atlcomtime.h>

COleDateTime dt = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();
COleDateTimeSpan span(90, 0, 0, 0);
COleDateTime dt2 = dt - span;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  time_t t = time(0);                      // NOW
  struct tm tm[1];
  memmove(tm, localtime(&t), sizeof tm);   // convert to struct tm
  tm->tm_mday -= 90;                       // subtract 90 days
  time_t then2 = mktime(tm);               // convert to time_t and normalize
  printf("%s\n", ctime(&then2));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the approach I would use other than to set the NOW date/time to noon and only print out the date (to avoid DST issues).  Doubt OP has looked into that level of concern.  Although maybe this code's non-adjustment of the `tm_isdst` field takes care of that,

Answer (score 0):

Not a single function, no.

But you can quite easily do this:

- Obtain current time using [`time()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time).
- Subtract 90 days' worth of seconds.
- Convert to local time using [`localtime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime).
- Convert to string using [`strftime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) if needed.

Answer (score -2):

DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90);

string edate  = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");